# How can I sort an array of objects by the objects' value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
[ 
    {   
        time: '5'
    },
    {
        time: '2'
    },
    {
        time: '3'
    }
]
```

Let's say I have an array of objects.  I want to sort it by time, ascending.  How can I do that in javascript?

Is there a generic function?

Example

```
var sorted_array = sortByKey(my_array, 'time', 'asc');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in `array.sort(somefunction)`

```
var data = [ 
    {   
        time: '5'
    },
    {
        time: '2'
    },
    {
        time: '3'
    }
];

data.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.time - b.time;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
my_array.sort(function(a,b) {return a.time - b.time});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
 jsArray = [ 
{   
    time: '5'
},
{
    time: '2'
},
{
    time: '3'
}
 ]

    jsArray.sort( function( tm1, tm2 ){
      return tm2.time - tm1.time;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArr = [
    {
        time: '5'
    },
    {
        time: '2'
    },
    {
        time: '3'
    }
];

myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.time, 10) - parseInt(b.time, 10);
});
```